# How can I inject custom data like factory in the ui router stateChangeStart function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am calling this:

```
$state.go("main.projects.selected.dates.day", { id: $state.params.id }, {reload: true});
```

I would really like to pass custom data from the state.go function to the stateChangeStart function. This is possible with the state params - which I could abuse to accept a date object - but then my url would not work anymore correctly...

How can I pass data from state.go to stateChangeStart? Just by hacking the rootScope.customData property?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, injectCustomFactory here)
{
   // Run custom logic here on the injected custom factory

   // then change the toParams.customData property by assigning the injected value to this property.

}
```

WHY do I have to run this logic in the stateChangeStart you might ask.

Its because only there I can check wether the user changed the url actively ($rootScope.customData is then falsy) or a state.go is done from outside and before I do a $rootScope.customData = MyValueLogic;

Answer (score 2):

Inject it in the run (or wherever you're watching `$stateChangeStart`):

```
angular.module('lalala').run(function ($rootScope, factory) {
    $rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState, ...) {
        factory.doSomething();
    });
});
```